# Calculate object Roll, Pitch and Yaw

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, affine-geometry, angle

I'd like to compute the Roll, Pitch, and Yaw angles of the following Parallelogram. I have the x,y,z coordinates of each of the corners (A,B,C,D) with respect to the reference point. Could anyone help out? Thanks.

http://postimg.org/image/fs7rqunt1/

Comment: This is a well worked problem. Look for solutions for affine transformations. If it is a practical problem you faced at your job, get a consultant to solve for you the problem.

Comment: I looked into it, and it seems like that ATs are used for rotations, translations, and scale operations. I am not interested in any of those operations. I simply would like to know how to calculate the orientation angles (roll, pitch, and yaw) of the object.